# How work this code? indirect obscuration ->

Tags: c++

I found the following example in a C++ textbook:

```
179: Part* PartsList::Find(
180:     int & position,
181:     int PartNumber) const
182: {
183:     PartNode * pNode = 0;
184:     for (pNode = pHead, position = 0;
185:        pNode!=NULL;
186:        pNode = pNode->GetNext(), position++)
187:     {
188:        if (pNode->GetPart()->GetPartNumber()== PartNumber)
189:            break;
190:     }
191:     if (pNode == NULL)
192:        return NULL;
193:     else
194:        return pNode->GetPart();
195: }
```

I have a problem with the line 188.

we compare:

```
pNode->GetPart()->GetPartNumber()
```

with this

```
PartNumber
```

but how do I read this?

I know:

```
pNode->Samefunc() // we call some func
pNew=pNode->Samefunc() // we copy to pNew some value. who returned Samefunc()
```

but I don't know how to read line 188, and what happen there.

Comment: `pNode->GetPart()->GetPartNumber()` is a function which returns an int, this is then compare to `PartNumber`. It does not need to be saved into a variable as it is being used immediately in the same expression. Which part specifically is unclear?

Comment: What function is calling. `GetPart` or `GetPartNumber; ` or sum `GetPart  and GetPartnNumber` compare with `PartnNumn`, that i dont understand.

Comment: You need to read from left to right. `pNode->GetPart()` is returning an object, on which you call `GetPartNumber()` that returns an `int`. Now you are justing comparing this int with `PartNumber` which is another `int`

Comment: big thanks you all. You all very help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
pNode->GetPart()->GetPartNumber()
```

calls `GetPartNumber()` on the result of `pNode->GetPart()`.
In your case it's the same as this:

```
auto temp = pNode->GetPart();
auto result = temp->GetPartNumber();
```

The `result` is then compared to `PartNumber` in the usual way.